# Area of described parametric region

Tags: calculus, parametric

The problem is as follows:

> A rope is tied to a cow and attached to the side of a circular silo with radius $r$. If the rope has length $\pi r$, what is the area of the land available for grazing by the cow?

Since this comes from the chapter on parametric equations, the first thing I did was to find the coordinates $(x,y)$ of the cow in terms of $\theta$:

[image]

The result was 
$$x=r(1+\cos\theta+\theta\sin\theta)$$
$$y=r(\sin\theta-\theta\cos\theta)$$

Now, to find the area of the region in the first quadrant, I set up the integral
$$\int_a^b x\, dy$$
$$=r^2\int_0^\pi \theta\sin\theta\,(1+\cos\theta+\theta\sin\theta)\,d\theta$$

My question is, how do I find the anti-derivative of the integrand? Or is there an easier way to solve this problem (either with parametric equations or without)?

Comment: Area between circle and its involute

Answer (score 3):

The differential form $\omega=x\,dy$ isn’t the only one that’ll give you the area swept out by the radius vector when integrated. Any other form $\tau =\omega+df$ will also work. A convenient choice can be $\frac12(x\,dy-y\,dx)$, which is the area of the triangle defined by $(x,y)$ and $(x+dx,y+dy)$. This yields, after simplification, $$\frac{r^2}2(\theta^2+\theta\sin\theta)\,d\theta$$ for the integrand, which looks a lot more manageable.

Comment: BTW, @Narasimham’s suggestion of centering the silo at the origin is good. That removes a term from $x(\theta)$ and ultimately changes the $\theta\sin\theta$ term above to $\cos^2\theta$. Which one is easier to integrate is a toss-up, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates choice is convenient.

A diagram of taut string around circular silo needs to be drawn to describe required part of the involute locus. From unwound length $ r\theta$  and radius $r$ by Pythagoras thm we compute radius to center of silo:

$$ \rho = r \sqrt{1+\theta^2} $$

Area $$ = \frac12 \int_0 ^{\pi-\tan^{-1} \pi  }  \rho^2 d \theta - \pi r^2/2 $$

You can take it further.

Comment: I suggest using a different variable for the parameter $\theta$ in the expression for $\rho$, since it’s not the angle made with the $x$-axis by the ray to the end of the rope, which is how the integral for the area appears to be using that variable. Then it would be clearer that $d\theta$ in that integral is also a function of that same parameter, I think.

Comment: Centering the silo on the origin certainly makes the integrand simple, but I’m not so sure that ending up with powers of $\tan^{-1}\pi$ after integrating is so convenient.